# Get js script to added content with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have infinite scroll on my website. My script append a few posts to actual page.

> $.ajax({
>
> > ```
> >          type: "POST",
> >             url: "infinite_scroll.php",
> >             data:data,
> >             success: function(res) {
> >                 $.getScript( "fx/js/post.js" );
> >                 $('#main-content').append(res);
> >                 $(window).scroll(scrollFunction);
> >         }
> >         });
> > ```

With every set of posts I want to getScript  'post.js'.

Is there any way to make this script workinkg only for added content ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap added content in a div element and set an id for it and then use this id in the script(script.js) that you load after adding content.

```
<div id="wrapper01">
    <div id="post01">...</div>
    <div id="post02">...</div>
    <div id="post03">...</div>
</div>
```

Note: set different id (here wrapper01) for every block that you get from server.

Note: because you script is a js file you cannot change it on the fly. instead of script.js you can use a php file and use  tag in the php file. and then generate script for the wrapper that you want(with specified id).

Comment: Yes, I know this solution. I wonder if exists any solution on jQuery side ?

Comment: I think it wont be possible. because you may have any code in your script.js file that is independent from DOM. for example logging something. if you post your script.js here maybe i can suggest better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use .unbind() on event, which is using for some js action, for example .unbind(click)